# SQL Server outputs inconsistent data

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm getting strange results for this query.

```
<?
include('conf/conector.php');
echo "start";
$connSQL = mssql_connect($AconnSQL[$CONF_connSQL_default][1], $AconnSQL[$CONF_connSQL_default][2], $AconnSQL[$CONF_connSQL_default][3]);
mssql_select_db($AconnSQL[$CONF_connSQL_default][4],$connSQL);
$result = mssql_query("SELECT TOP 300 coditm, descripcion, codsbr FROM items WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE itemprefi='B' AND descripcion != '' AND descripcion IS NOT NULL");
echo "<br>rows: ".mssql_num_rows($result).'<br>';
mssql_free_result($result);
mssql_close($connSQL);
echo "end";
include('../includes/funciones/conector_by.php');
?>
```

The above code prints "rows: 300". It's expected because of the "TOP 300".

BUT if I run (using the same code):

```
SELECT coditm, descripcion, codsbr
FROM items WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE itemprefi='B' AND descripcion != '' AND descripcion IS NOT NULL
```

It prints "rows: 272" (I also get 272 lines if I execute a 'while' with mssql_fetch_array).

If I put "TOP 500" I also get 272 lines.

It's just crazy but it gets crazier...

If I run:

```
SELECT count(*) as test
FROM items WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE itemprefi='B' AND descripcion != '' AND descripcion IS NOT NULL
```

test column is 1936 (which is the real number of rows).

I'm completely confused, I don't know where to search for an error. I've been using mssql_* for a long time (in the same server) and I've never got a problem like this. It only happends with this table.

Comment: Do you have the table indexed?

Comment: I would think that some of the results may be duplicates. Try using key word distinct and see what you get

Comment: I don't know if the table is indexed because I only have remote access. I tried using count(coditm) and I got 1936.

Comment: Using count(distinct coditm) I got "1".